# Unable to open flight recorder in JMC for Java application and Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jmc, jfr

When I try to run flight recorder it takes a very long time in loading and then crashes, and throws an exception after a while:

> Connection refused to host: 17.226.xx.yyyy; nested exception is:
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect to [1.8.0_181] Eclipse
>   (2092). Make sure the JVM is running and that you are using the
>   correct protocol in the Service URL
>   (service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/stub/rO0ABXN9AAAAAQAlamF2YXgubWFuYWdlbWVudC5yZW1vdGUucm1pLlJNSVNlcnZlcnhyABdqYXZhLmxhbmcucmVmbGVjdC5Qcm94eeEn2iDMEEPLAgABTAABaHQAJUxqYXZhL2xhbmcvcmVmbGVjdC9JbnZvY2F0aW9uSGFuZGxlcjt4cHNyAC1qYXZhLnJtaS5zZXJ2ZXIuUmVtb3RlT2JqZWN0SW52b2NhdGlvbkhhbmRsZXIAAAAAAAAAAgIAAHhyABxqYXZhLnJtaS5zZXJ2ZXIuUmVtb3RlT2JqZWN002G0kQxhMx4DAAB4cHc4AAtVbmljYXN0UmVmMgAADTE3LjIyNi4yMC4yMjQAAMF44tzu6CRJNeORCVrBAAABZN4+pbCAAQB4).

I have tried running different version of jdks: from java 7 to java 8:

```
jdk1.7.0_80.jdk
jdk1.8.0_141.jdk
jdk1.8.0_144.jdk
jdk1.8.0_162.jdk
jdk1.8.0_181.jdk
```

Also, uninstalled eclipse and installed back STS back. Still the issue is there. Looks like issue is somehwhere in jmc not able to connect to eclipse and/or tomcat jvm.

Anyone who has resolved similar issue please help on that. Thanks.

Update: I am able to record flights using command terminal by using

jcmd $pid JFR.start name=MyRecording settings=default duration=60s

jcmd $pid JFR.dump name=MyRecording filename=/tmp/test_TIMESTAMP.jfr

Still I am clueless why it would not run from gui.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to open flight recorder now with a "hack".
To make it work I had to add -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost vm arg in the server configs of my JEE application.